# Drawing custom indoor map and links between locations. For each location x,y coordinates are already know to be shown on screen

Tags: android

[image]

```
package com.smallfan.museumexhibition.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomDrawableView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    Drawable drawable;
     Paint paint;
     String myText;
     int x1,y1;
     Context context;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context, Drawable mydrawable, int x, int y, String text) {
        super(context);

        this.myText=text;
        this.x1=x;
        this.y1=y;
        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.context=context;

        drawable=mydrawable;

        drawable.setBounds(x, y, x + drawable.getMinimumWidth(), y + drawable.getMinimumHeight());

        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    { 
        v.setTag(myText);
        Toast.makeText(context, "View clicked. "+"  tag  "+ v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

package com.smallfan.museumexhibition;

import java.io.InputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MapInActivity extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("MapInActivity", "onCreate()");
    }

    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.v("MapInActivity", "onCreateView()");

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.indoormap_layout, null);
        RelativeLayout maplayout=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.maplayout);


        CustomDrawableView   mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(getActivity(),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher),10,10,"Item 1");
        maplayout.addView(mCustomDrawableView);

        CustomDrawableView   mCustomDrawableView1 = new CustomDrawableView(getActivity(),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher),50,50,"Item 2");
        maplayout.addView(mCustomDrawableView1);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("MapInActivity", "onActivityCreated().");
    }
    //

}
```

---

I have to draw a map like this and also show the overlay on tap of any pin like in Google map. I was able to draw views on canvas along with click listeners, but the click listener action is performed by clicking any where on screen and it's just for the view drawn in last. So if any solution then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of GeoFencing ? The only catch is that it works on the principle of a circle. But that should not be that bad, since you can cover the entrance with 2 circles, 1 that covers the breath of the room and includes the entrance door, and the other circle contained within the bigger circle that only covers the door.

Check out A4, I have drawn 2 circles, sorry for a ugly representation.

[image: illustration]

If a user enters the smaller circle and the bigger circle than he is still in the room. If he enters the smaller circle and exists it (and is not entering the bigger circle) he has exited the room.

Twisted but will work with minimal coding. Just read up geofencing.

Also note geofencing is now merged with LocationClient API's which consume 8 times lesser battery as compared to LocationManager. So go for it.